# Why are we counting some combinations more than once in this problem?

Tags: combinatorics

> Given $6$ purses, $9$ flaps and $12$ straps. Every combination must include $1$ purse, $1$ flap and $1$ strap. How many total combinations are there?

My solution is $6 \cdot 9 \cdot 12$. However, the textbook shows this number divided by $3!$. What is wrong and which combinations are being counted more than once?

Comment: There is no need to divide by 3! since your 3 elements are distinguishable. The book is giving a wrong answer.